# Get rows which do not contain 0

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to make a new matrix from another matrix but only with rows which do not contain 0, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it could by done very simply

```
x <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

y <- cbind (x[which(x[,1]*x[,2] >0), 1:2])
```

Comment: Excludes the case where some value is less than 0.

Comment: You have a lot of redundant code. `x[x[,1]*x[,2] != 0, 1:2]` would do it. But that's difficult to generalize to bigger matrices

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more vectorized way.

```
x <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

x[rowSums(x==0)==0,]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am only piecing together the great suggestions others have already given.  I like the ability to store this as a function and generalize to values besides 1 including categorcal values (also selects positively or negatively using the select argument):

```
v.omit <- function(dataframe, v = 0, select = "neg") {
    switch(select, 
        neg = dataframe[apply(dataframe, 1, function(y) !any(y %in% (v))), ],  
        pos = dataframe[apply(dataframe, 1, function(y) any(y %in% (v))), ])
}
```

Let's try it.

```
x <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,NA,1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

v.omit(x)
v.omit(mtcars, 0)
v.omit(mtcars, 1)
v.omit(CO2, "chilled") 
v.omit(mtcars, c(4,3))
v.omit(CO2, c('Quebec', 'chilled'))
v.omit(x, select="pos")
v.omit(CO2, c('Quebec', 'chilled'), select="pos")
v.omit(x, NA)
v.omit(x, c(0, NA))
```

Please do not mark my answer as the correct one as others have answered before me, this is just to extend the conversation.  Thanks for the code and the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways, but here's one approach. We'll use `apply()` and the `all()` function to create a boolean vector to index into the matrix of interest.

```
x <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
x
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    0
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    1    1
> x[apply(x, 1, function(y) all(y > 0)) ,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
```

Comment: Excludes possibility of less than 0.

Comment: !any(y==0) takes care of the case where you have negative values in your matrix.

Comment: You can make this slightly more compact, I think: `x[apply(x>0,1,all),]` (or `x[apply(x!=0,1,all),]`)